# Return SQL result from function as array

Tags: python

Since the query returns more than 1 result, at the Get_results class how could i return the data_out as an array in order to iterate on the results of the query?

```
import psycopg2
import sys

class Get_results():
    def db_call(self,query,dbHost,dbName,dbUser,dbPass):
        try:
            con = None
            con = psycopg2.connect(host=dbHost, database=dbName,
                                   user=dbUser, password=dbPass)
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute(query)
            data = cur.fetchall()
            for data_out in data:
                return data_out
        except psycopg2.DatabaseError, e:
                print 'Error %s' % e
                sys.exit(1)
        finally:
            if con:
                con.close()

 sql = " some sql "
 w = Get_results()
 for i in  w.db_call(sql, dbHost, dbName, dbUser, dbPass):
     print "The result is : " + i
```

For aditional info, when if i add `print data` right after  `data = cur.fetchall()` i have the result:

```
[('The_Galaxy', 'The_Galaxy:star'),
 ('The_Galaxy', 'The_Galaxy:planet')]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import psycopg2
import sys

class Get_results():
    def db_call(self,query,dbHost,dbName,dbUser,dbPass):
        try:
            con = None
            con = psycopg2.connect(host=dbHost, database=dbName,
                                   user=dbUser, password=dbPass)
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute(query)
            data = cur.fetchall()  
            resultList = []  
            for data_out in data:  
                resultList.append(data_out[1])  


            return resultList   
        except psycopg2.DatabaseError, e:
                print 'Error %s' % e
                sys.exit(1)
        finally:
            if con:
                con.close()

 sql = " some sql "
 w = Get_results()
 for i in  w.db_call(sql, dbHost, dbName, dbUser, dbPass):
     print "The result is : " + i
```

Comment: this will print the value of column with index 0. To print other columns just change the index value in the return statement i.e. resultList.append(data_out[n])

Comment: I tried your solution, but im still receiving one result only.

Comment: Hi, the sql is simple , is "select * from table" it returns only 2 values.

Comment: is it printing The_Galaxy twice in the result? if so use resultList.append(data_out[1]) and check the output.

Comment: Prashant, really sorry, the code you described works. the failure was mine for inserting the  return resultList inside the for data_out loop. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 4):

The immediate answer is to change:

```
for data_out in data:
    data_out result
```

to:

```
for data_out in data:
    yield data_out
```

But you should look at using a `with` statement (if the DB API supports it), and simplifying the code - this could just be done by making a generator function (a class is OTT for this)

Comment: Hi, there was a mistake on the code, i updated the line data_out result to return data_out

Comment: @Thales Right - but either yield each row, or just return the cursor and iterate over that...