# How to fill an array with values from sql Python

Tags: python

Hello i am new in python and im trying to learn basic things, right now i have made a query that gets `chat_ID` from database and i want to insert all the results inside an array but i cant make the values enter inside the array, this is the code i have done until now:

```
 query = "SELECT `chatid` FROM `chats`"
        cursor = await self.db.execute(query)
        record = await cursor.fetchall() 
        
        for row in record:
        chats_id = [row] #the array
```

I want the result to be

```
chats_id = ["1","2","3","4"];
```

Comment: list(row) should work

Comment: how do i make that `chats_id = list(row)`  ?

Comment: Try looking at [Return SQL result from function as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12900477/return-sql-result-from-function-as-array).

Comment: Depends. What are you trying to accomplish with chats_id ? If you gonna work row by row each loop iteration, then it's exactly what you suggested:  `  chats_id = list(row) ` .

Comment: i need to fill the array thats it so if i make `print(chats_id)` to get `["1"], ["2"]...`